# Upgrade to .Net 7 gets me an MS Graph Error: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Graph.IDriveItemCreateLinkRequestBuilder

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-7.0, microsoft-graph-sdks

I upgraded our .Net Core web application to .Net 7. Everything went pretty smooth for the most part. The solution built successfully, but we all know that doesn't mean everything will work. My application collects files from a SharePoint folder using Microsoft Graph. When it collects these files, it creates a link to the file. I am getting the following exception, which it looks lik it's related to the link.

```
Method not found: 'Microsoft.Graph.IDriveItemCreateLinkRequestBuilder Microsoft.Graph.IDriveItemRequestBuilder.CreateLink(System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1<System.DateTimeOffset>, System.String, System.String)'.
```

I tried to google this one and could not find anything, except a possible licensing issue under a link from Microsoft. That known issue doesn't seem to be related. Anyone got any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Someone asked which version of Graph I'm using and for a code sample. I am currently using MS Graph 4.11.0. The link code is below:

```
var link = await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[docFolderId].Items[file.Id].CreateLink("edit", "organization").Request().PostAsync();
formfile.FileLink = link.Link.WebUrl;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please share the code? How do you call CreateLink method? Which version of Graph SDK do you use?

Comment: Hello - Thanks for your response. I updated the question with the MS Graph version and a code snippet for the link.

Comment: could you first update the MS Graph SDK to the latest version. 
try code like this:
`var linkRequest = _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[docFolderId].Items[file.Id].CreateLink("edit", "organization").Request();
var link = await linkRequest.PostAsync();
formfile.FileLink = link.Link.WebUrl;`

Comment: I have upgraded the MS Graph client to 5.35 and now I'm getting errors about the IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage not being found.